# Rust Vulkano training. A problem with the rotating light source

Tags: rust, vulkan

I'm trying play with Rust and Vulkano library. I use [this tutorial series](https://taidaesal.github.io/vulkano_tutorial/section_11_5.html). I did some code changes for **vulkano = "0.34"**. Here is [my repo](https://github.com/nocl1p/miniature-adventure). I left a code repository here because I don't know what blocks of the code should be shown here. So for now I can'n understand one thing. I have the big sphere. Also I have a small sphere that is a light source which rotates around big sphere (like in the tutorial I've attached above). I see that the light falls on the left or right side of the big sphere, but it doesn't fall on the front side, and I can not understand why it is happen. As I understood the normals is calculated in proper way. If someone know what should I do to fix that

[image: Light sourse on the left side]

[image: Light sourse on the right side]

[image: Front side].

**Upd. The light falls on the back side. For now I can't understand why**
[image: Upd. The light falls on the back side]

Comment: Does this mean that if the light were behind the sphere that it would appear lit? Are you perhaps culling the wrong faces (i.e. the cull mode or face winding order aren't right)?

Comment: @kmdreko yes when the light is behind the sphere doesn't appear lit

Comment: Hmmmm... Eventually turns out that the big sphere appears lit from the back side. And front side don't. It's the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. I the directional light fragment shader I did a mistake

```
vec3 light_direction = normalize(directional.position.xyz - subpassLoad(u_normals).xyz);
```

But it should be

```
vec3 light_direction = normalize(directional.position.xyz + subpassLoad(u_normals).xyz);
```